# Should I keep a reference to the original Exception in the top Exception if another Exception eats it?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

Consider this custom `Exception` class:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final int EXCEPTION1 = 1;
    public static final int EXCEPTION2 = 2;
    public static final int EXCEPTION3 = 3;

    private int exceptionType;
    private Throwable guiltyException;

    public CustomException(String message, int type, Throwable cause){
        super(message);
        this.exceptionType = type;
        this.guiltyException = cause;
    }

    public int getExceptionType(){
        return this.exceptionType;
    }

    public Throwable getGuiltyException(){
        return this.guiltyException;
    }

}
```

And then assume there is somewhere a method such as this:

```
public SomeReturnType someMethod(SomeArgument argument) throws CustomException{
    try{
        someExceptionalMethodCall(); // Throws Exception1, Exception2, Exception3
    } catch (Exception1 e1) {
        throw new CustomException("Some info1", CustomException.EXCEPTION1, e1);
    } catch (Exception2 e2) {
        throw new CustomException("Some info2", CustomException.EXCEPTION2, e2);
    } catch (Exception3 e3) {
        throw new CustomException("Some info3", CustomException.EXCEPTION3, e3);
    }
}
```

Is storing the `Throwable` just meaningless overhead I could avoid by adjusting the `super` call to `Exception` in the constructor of `CustomException`? Like this:

```
public CustomException(String message, int type, Throwable cause){
    super(message, cause);
    this.exceptionType = type;
}
```

Then I could get rid of `guiltyException` and `getGuiltyException`.

**Is there any point in storing the** `Throwable` **cause in the** `CustomException` **class itself?**

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no reason to store the cause yourself when `Throwable` already has that facility. Your class should only introduce *extra* information, not duplicate fields which already have a meaning.

Aside from anything else, I would *expect* to be able to call `getCause()` and retrieve the original exception - whereas in your original code, I'd have to know that it's a `CustomException`, and call `getGuiltyException()`. One symptom of this is that any general purpose code logging the error won't see the cause in your current version - whereas it will if you use the standard approach to exception chaining.

Comment: Good call regarding the possible logging issues this might cause, didn't even think about that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to keep a reference to the exception cause since this can be set in the `super(message, cause)` constructor.